# Why is Git clone copying a different repository?

Tags: angularjs, git, github, bitbucket, git-clone

I'm following the [AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and am cloning the source code using the instructions:

> Clone the angular-phonecat repository located at GitHub by running the following command:
>   `git clone --depth=14 https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git`
>   This command creates the angular-phonecat directory in your current directory.

However, running this at
`~\users\myuser\development`
creates
`~\users\myuser\development\angular-phonecat`
but without the source code inside it. It creates the directory, but clones my personal bitbucket repository into the new directory.

Do I need to change a global or local setting or use another command or argument to force to git to pull from the repository declared in the command?

---

**EDIT**
The following commands and output should add some colour:

> machinename:development user$> git config --get remote.origin.url
>   https://stuperuser@bitbucket.org/stuperuser/spikes.git
>
> machinename:development user$> ls
>   spikes              sublime-projects
>
> machinename:development user$> git clone --depth=14 https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
>   Cloning into 'angular-phonecat'...
>   Password for 'https://stuperuser@bitbucket.org':
>   remote: Counting objects: 58, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
>   remote: Total 58 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   Unpacking objects: 100% (58/58), done.
>   Checking connectivity... done.
>
> machinename:development user$> ls
>   spikes              sublime-projects
>   angular-phonecat

Comment: That command looks just fine.  `git` may be magical in some ways but cloning is usually straightforward.  Can you confirm that the `angular-phonecat` does not exist prior to running the `clone` command, and can you cut and paste both your actual comand line and any output that `git clone` produces?

Comment: Please add the exact command you type with the exact output given by that command.

Comment: `~\users\myuser\development> git config --get remote.origin.url` returns one of my bitbucket respositories' .git urls.

Comment: Comments added. Looks like the development is mapped to spikes.git as well as development\spikes.

Comment: In fact running `~\users\myuser\> git config --get remote.origin.url` returns that bitbucket repository. Could I have set my entire global config to that one origin url?

Comment: Turns out git does exactly what you tell it to, even if you're daft enough to map the entire machine's origin to a single repository!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my
`~\.gitconfig`
global config, and I was pointing it to a single remote origin that was that particular repository.

Deleting that global setting and rerunning the command cloned the repository correctly.